# Global message displays, then re-displays on next page loaded

Tags: magento

We are having an issue with the comparison feature.  If a user removes an item from the compare popup, the global message "XYZ has been removed..." appears in the page under the popup.  That is expected behavior.  However, on the subsequent page load the same message appears "XYZ has been removed..."

So there is some sort of issue with the message not being removed from the queue.  We are using EE 1.10.1.1.  I thought it could be a hole punching issue, but why would it show twice? (hole punching would more likely be that it doesn't show at first, but then shows up 1+ pages later)

It may be relevant that the theme appears to have been built using some files from the Community version.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  (sorry no code included, just not sure where the issue could be)

Answer (score 0):

It's a caching problem. The message is cached. I suggest you to install [Template Hints](https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_TemplateHints) extension. It can show you in what block the flash message has been cached.

Comment: I added a timestamp to the message to see if it was being called twice or once and being re-displayed from cache and you are correct that it is a caching issue. Usually when we see a caching issue it is that the message gets delayed because there isn't a place in punch through.  However, in this case it is punching through twice which is odd.

Comment: One thing worth adding, is that if I add another item to the comparison after removing one, I get both the cached removal message and the new addition message.  I would have though if the block was cached I would only get the removal message again.

Comment: Surely, messages are cached by block HTML cache. Use Template Hints extension to find in what block/template this message is cached.